# Is there a way to instantly upload files at dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Is there a programmatic way to instantly upload files at dropbox to ensure that some desired files was sent to the cloud without wait the desktop application sync process.

The ideal case would be:

```
$ dropbox-command upload-now ~/Dropbox/subfolder
```

Thanks

Comment: Like [this](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader) one?

Comment: Yes, [Dropbox has an API](http://dropbox.com/developers).

Comment: @Martheen thanks I will check this out!